# How to hide the first element on the page with particular css class?

Tags: html, css

In CSS (not javascript), how can I hide the first element with a particular class, but not the other elements? See example below:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <center>
    <a href="" class="button">hide this one</a>
  </center>
<div> Some other stuff</div>
  <center>
    <a href="" class="button">don't hide this one</a>
  </center>
</div>
```

How would I hide the **first** element with the class of button?

Comment: Adding one more class to the first element will be better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option would be to use the `nth-of-type` selector:

```
.button:nth-of-type(1) {
  display:none;
}
```

**Note:** This selector is supported in IE9+, Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera (but not older versions of IE).

Also, it's time to remove the `<center>` tags. They have been **removed** as of HTML5.

Replace it with the equivalent CSS:

```
a.button {
  text-align:center;
}
```

[**Here's a working jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ljhpb/4/)

Answer (score 1):

With the [`:first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3afirst-of-type) CSS selector:

```
a.button:first-of-type { display: none; }
```

Beware of browser compatibility (IE < 9 is not supported), and also note that this will only work because all the elements under consideration are siblings; if they were scattered throughout the document tree it would not be possible to do this with pure CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your code to work with older version browser (IE8 etc). use jquery.

http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-toggle-example-to-display-and-hide-content/

**The example:**

```
<html>
 <head>
    <title>jQuery toggle to display and hide content</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('.nav-toggle').click(function(){
            //get collapse content selector
            var collapse_content_selector = $(this).attr('href');                   

            //make the collapse content to be shown or hide
            var toggle_switch = $(this);
            $(collapse_content_selector).toggle(function(){
              if($(this).css('display')=='none'){
                                //change the button label to be 'Show'
                toggle_switch.html('Show');
              }else{
                                //change the button label to be 'Hide'
                toggle_switch.html('Hide');
              }
            });
          });

        }); 
        </script>
        <style> 
        .round-border {
            border: 1px solid #eee;
            border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
            -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
            -moz-border-radius: 4px;
            border-radius: 4px;
            padding: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section class="round-border">
            <h2>jQuery toggle() to hide/show collapse content</h2>
            <div>
                <button href="#collapse1" class="nav-toggle">Show</button>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse1" style="display:none">
                <p>Bla bla bla bla</p>
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

better to add a special class with preprocessor. Because "first-of-type", "nth-of-child" and similars a not working in browsers